# Finding the centre of the circle on the complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers

The centre of the circle represented  by $|z+1|$=$2|z-1|$ on the complex plane is

(a)0

(b)5/3

(c)1/3

(d)None of these

What I've tried so far in attached in the pic below. Please refer to it

[image]

[image]

Comment: You might attract more respondents/proofreaders if you type up your work. Just a suggestion. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: mathjax  this, also what is the part you have problem with?

Comment: I have calculated the roots, but as mathlove said I have an error. Also, I dont know what to do next.

Comment: I find writing everything very cumbersome and time consuming. As I am a student, I dont have much time. Kindly bear with me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error from

$$\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}=2\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}$$
to
$$(x+1)^2=4(x-1)^2.$$

It should be
$$(x+1)^2+y^2=4\left((x-1)^2+y^2\right)\implies (x+1)^2+y^2=4(x-1)^2+\color{red}{4}y^2$$
After this, try to have a form of $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the mistake out. Can you please help me proceed? How can I find the centre?

Comment: @Abhishekstudent: I added an explanation.

Comment: Where did you get "r" from?

Comment: @Abhishekstudent: It is just a constant representing the radius. Just expand the expression and try to have the form I wrote at the end.

Comment: @Abhishekstudent: Don't you know that $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$ represents a circle whose center is $(a,b)$ with radius $r$?

Comment: I didnt know that! Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: @Abhishekstudent: You may want to see [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Equations).